# UWP ListBox ForEach

Tags: c#, uwp, listbox, listboxitem

I'm trying to loop through a UWP ListBox.

My XAML:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="SeasonsListBox" Margin="786,24,558,863" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <ListBoxItem Content="2016-2017"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="2017-2018"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="2018-2019"/>
    </ListBox>
```

And here is my code behind:

```
        var items = SeasonsListBox.Items;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            string temp = item.ToString();
        }
```

I'm trying to get the Content, but it doesn't allow me to `item.Content.ToString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try:

```
string temp = (item as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks Aly, Thats the ticket.